# Accessing Classes from an external project folder in C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, assembly, namespaces, using

First off here is my file structure

```
Services.Abstraction.Common
Services.Abstraction.Claims
Services.Abstraction.Clearance
```

In Visiual Studio 2010, I am in the Claims project and I want to access classes from the Common layer which is on the same level as both Claims and Clearance.  I use the namespace below in the Claims project.  However it is saying the Common doesn't exists and all the functions that are in the Common folder also don't exist.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Services.Abstraction.Common;
```

How do I fix this?  Do I have it wrong in the namespace or do I have to add something to my assembly?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the assembly in your project references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.80).aspx

There is not much to say here... this link explain you how to add a reference in visual studio, probably you problem is that you are missing a reference to the other dll or project, am I wrong?